# Cannot access data inside multiple children tags from within an ng-repeat directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to pull off the following block of code using ng-repeat.

```
<tr ng-repeat="category in categoryList">
<td>{{category.name}}</td>
<td>{{category.customersWaiting}}</td>
<td>{{category.waitingTime}}</td>
</tr>
```

Unfortunately it seems category is not accessible inside the last two td tags. I have tried all sorts of variations using ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end. None of them are working. I can only access category in the first  element. Can someone please show me how to layout out my tags using the correct directive to solve this particular problem. I need to essentially repeat the tr tag for each item in the array with the three td tags in each row. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the data in categoryList?

Comment: [{name: "Lakmal", customersWaiting : 2, waitingTime : 30023}, .. etc]

Answer (score 1):

I think an issue is somewhere else because putting this into a Plnkr reveals everything working just fine. Could you elaborate what your issue is?

http://plnkr.co/edit/9VLkEQiEFuReC1dPa2iC?p=preview

This is the array of data that I've used

```
$scope.categoryList = [
{
  name: 'first',
  customersWaiting: 20,
  waitingTime: 2300
},
{
  name: 'second',
  customersWaiting: 40,
  waitingTime: 230
}]
```

With the same markup

```
<tr ng-repeat="category in categoryList">
    <td>{{category.name}}</td>
    <td>{{category.customersWaiting}}</td>
    <td>{{category.waitingTime}}</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Omg thank you soo much. I thought i was losing it. I was trying to execute a function inside the {{}} like so {{formatTime(category.waitingTime)}}. Apparently that doesn't work. I thought an expression was evaluated inside the  {{}} within the controller scope.